# Akka-stream. Combining materialized-values. Need to map futures. Which ExecutionContext/Dispatcher to use?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

**Given:**

- `AtoB: GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[A, B, Future[AtoBRuntimeApi]]`;
- `BtoC: GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[B, C, Future[BtoCRuntimeApi]]`.

**Wanted:** `AtoC: GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[A, C, Future[AtoCRuntimeApi]]`.

In my particular case it's really convenient to implement `AtoCRuntimeApi` in terms of both `AtoBRuntimeApi` and `BtoARuntimeApi`.

So I would like to define `AtoCRuntimeApi` as `case class AtoCRuntimeApi(a2b: AtoBRuntimeApi, b2c: BtoCRuntimeApi)`;

And to define the new compound stage as `stageAtoB.viaMat(stageBtoC)(combineIntoAtoC)` where
`combineIntoAtoC: (Future[AtoBRuntimeApi], Future[B2CRuntimeApi]) => Future[AtoCRuntimeApi]`.

Obviously the implementation of `combineIntoAtoC` requires some instance of `ExecutionContext` in order to map the futures.

**The question: what execution context should I use in the described case?**

Options, I would rather avoid:

- bake in an instance that is currently available (while composition of stages) — the "blueprint" will not be safe to materialise if that execution-context becomes unavailable;
- `ExecutionContext.global` — well, it's global. It seems terribly wrong to use it (probably, once per materialisation — is not that big deal).

The most wanted execution-context is the one that is available as the property of materializer (`mat.executionContext`). But there is no way I can access it within that combine-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the actor system context in such cases, which is indeed by default can be referred to from the materializer. As a general solution, though, you can pass the execution context to whatever function you construct the stream graph in with an implicit parameter:

```
def makeGraph(...)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): RunnableGraph = {
  def combineIntoAtoC(...) = ...  // uses ec implicitly
}
```

This allows you to push the decision about which context to use up the call stack. At the appropriate level there most certainly will be some kind of access to the actor system's dispatcher.

The reason why I prefer to use the actor system's dispatcher instead of the global one is because it reduces the surface of dependencies - all execution contexts in this case come from one source, and you know how to configure them if the need arises.

Comment: Alas this seems to be a slightly clumsy solution for me: if some component expects a `Flow[ByteString, ProtocolEvent]`, I will have to choose some ExCtx at the moment of passing the flow to the component.

How bad in your opinion is the idea to use something similar to `akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts.sameThreadExecutionContext`?
(Something like:
`ExecutionContext.fromExecutor { command: Runnable => command.run() }`)

Comment: Depends on what you do in the combination function. If it is a simple tupling function, then it is probably okay. But still, I don't think having an execution context passed around as an implicit argument is that problematic, because in akka-based and future-based applications you have to do it anyway, and execution context can usually be obtained quite easily - in actors, for example, it can be retrieved from `context`.

Comment: I found no option other than  
a) requiring an instance of `ExecutionContext` as an argument to create a `Graph[Shape, Mat]`;  
b) using a kind of `sameThreadExecutionContext` if the mapping consists of "re-tupling" only.  
  
Thanks, a lot.